# Ejecutar código solo por cierto definido tiempo en C#

Tags: c#

Quiero saber si es posible estar ejecutando un método por un tiempo definido, por ejemplo estar mostrando el resultado de una suma solo por 5 segundos, de ahí finalizar ese procedimiento y pasar a la ejecución normal de lo demás.

Comment: Puedes usar un timer y establecer que al finalizar te oculte lo que estabas mostrando, puedes hacer un Timer.Sleep para bloquear las demas operaciones por un tiempo definido, el diapasón de respuesta es bastante amplio solo tienes que formular mejor la pregunta incluso agregando aprte de codigo que hayas elaborado ya para poder encaminarte mejor.

Comment: Un método no se va a ejecutar por un "tiempo definible", simplemente se ejecuta y demora los milisegundos que demore y se acabó. Lo que te quieres es que luego de pasado cierto tiempo se ejecute algún código.

Comment: Ejecutar un metodo y mostrar el resultado en pantalla son cosas muy distintas. Partamos de la base que un metodo ejecuta y termina, salvo que lo frenes con un sleep del thread (hilo de ejecucion). Ahora si vas a mostrar algo en pantalla deberias dar mas detalles de como quieres lograr esta interaccion, sera un form en popup que muestr ele valor y se cierra, sera un label en la misma pantalla que aparece y luego se oculta. Edita la pregunta y explicate mas completo.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que utilices el objeto `Timer` el cual te permite ejecutar cierto código por un tiempo predefinido , te dejo el siguiente [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8) para que lo revises.